# Adding a picture header to an HTML email

Tags: c#, email, html-email

I'm trying to send an automated email from an application.
The main problem I'm having is that the picture doesn't display.
Secondary to that, the actual resource I'm supposed to be using is a PSD file I can only access with a URL.

The attach code is in from previous experiments, it attaches the file I select from the dialog in line 3

So can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
try{
            OpenFileDialog diag = new OpenFileDialog();
            diag.ShowDialog();

            FileInfo inf = new FileInfo(diag.FileName);


            string htmlBody = "<html><header><h1>TestPic</h1><br><img src=\"cid:filename\"></header></html>";
            AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
               (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(@inf.FullName, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            inline.ContentLink = new Uri("PSD_Url.com");

            avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

            Attachment att = new Attachment(inf.FullName);
            att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

            mail.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Test Email";
            mail.Body = String.Format(
                       "<h3>TEST Has Sent You A Mail</h3>" +
                       @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", inline.ContentId);



            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Attachments.Add(att);
            mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            mail.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            SmtpClient smp = new SmtpClient("mailhost.com", 80);
            smp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"from@gmail.com", @"password");
            smp.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;

            smp.Send(mail);
 }
 catch(SmtpException sEx)
 {
  throw sEx;  
 }
```

Comment: If you use `src="cid:filename"`, shouldn't you then use `inline.ContentId = "filename";` to link the two?

Answer (score 0):

.PSD files will not render in most email clients. They are limited to .JPG, .PNG and .GIF. In your case, you might want to run your .PSD through imagemagick or some image converter to convert it first.

Besides that, make sure the image URL is absolute and hosted online and it should work.